# PHP Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array:

```
    $y_exceptions = array(
    "lay",
    "interlay",
    "display",
    "delay",
    "obey",
    "decay",
    "play",
    "slay"
);
```

I'm checking if a word is in my array like this:

```
foreach($y_exceptions as $thisException) {
```

Which throws the error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce, works just fine ?

Comment: Looks probable that something modifies $y_exceptions between the creation and foreach.

Comment: Impossible to reproduce the error with this code and informations

Comment: I am using this file in an iframe...would that affect it? (And no, I'm not changing the variable between the creation and the foreach)

Comment: Why not use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php)?

Comment: try a var_dump $y_exceptions just before the foreach statement and see what it gives perhaps it could help

Comment: It looks like you need to add a little bit more of your code in order for people to see what's really going on with it.

Comment: Chances are is that your `$y_exceptions` array was set to `null` before the `foreach` loop. A `null` is not treated as an array, which the `foreach` expects, hence the warning. Try putting an `if (!isset($y_exceptions)) { ... }` and/or `if (!empty($y_exceptions)) { ... }` conditional in there somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$y_exceptions` needs to be an array for it to be processed by a foreach loop. It is possible that `$y_exceptions` was set to `null` before the foreach loop. A `null` is not treated as an array, which the foreach expects—hence the warning.

On solution would be stricter validation before the foreach:

```
if (!is_array($y_exceptions)) {
    // throw an exception
}
```

Alternatively, you could instruct the foreach loop to run `$y_exceptions` as an array, though this may cause errors downstream:

```
foreach ((array) $y_exceptions as $thisException) {
    // do stuff
}
```